What explains the definition of true and false in untyped lambda calculus?
In lambda calculus, the Church encoding defines "true" and "false" as:
true := λx.λy.x
false := λx.λy.y

Interpreted conceptually, this would seem to say that "truth" is a binary function which returns its first argument, whereas "false" is a binary function which returns its second argument. This does not correspond to common intuition for what "true" and "false" are. I would say true and false are values, which are furthermore defined in relation to each other in certain ways.
In untyped lambda calculus, the only type is the expression. So we can begin to motivate this choice of definition by noting that if true and false are to be values somewhere in this language, they will have to be lambda expressions. It would occur to me to include them as variables, then: true ∈ Variables, false ∈ Variables, and consider what relationships they need to have.
For example, in algebra, the relationship of truthhood to falsehood can be captured in a Boolean algebra. A Boolean algebra relates true and false to each other under certain operations: and, or, not, implies, and certain identities: true and true is true, not not true is true, etc.
So I guess we can deduce the definition of not, because we know what values it should have: not λx.λy.x = λx.λy.y, not λx.λy.y = λx.λy.x. One expression that does this is λp.λa.λb.pba. This is an example derivation:

Does this mean that the definitions of true and false in lambda calculus may seem initially difficult to conceptually interpret, but are so chosen because they exhibit the desired relational behavior of these values? Or do they have an interesting interpretation?

Indeed in lambda calculus everything is treated as an expression and every concept, including truth and falsehood, must be represented as a lambda expression or specifically a particular abstraction chosen by Church. The Church encoding of true and false is a way to model Boolean values where true and false are not values in the traditional absolute external sense but rather functions that capture certain behaviors when applied to the context of two argument terms thus its application's normalization result as truth value becomes context-sensitive not unlike the grammar of natural languages...

One way of understanding the standard λ-calculus encodings is as folds over the corresponding algebraic datatypes. E.g. natural numbers can be defined in Haskell notation as data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat, the values are Zero, Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), ..., and the folds are (up to a choice of argument order) λsz.z, λsz.sz, λsz.s(sz), ..., which are the Church numerals.
If you apply the same prescription to data Bool = False | True, you get False = λtf.f, True = λtf.t, again up to a choice of argument order. This order has the advantage that if a then b else c translates to abc.

"This order has the advantage ...". I had forgotten about that. +1 for reminding me of that nice fact.

+1 Not an ounce of fat on this response. "This order has the advantage that if a then b else c translates to abc." AKA syntactic sugar to the casual reader.

If you're going to think in lambda calculus, you have to remember that everything is a function. There are no  constants. Those are functions that evaluate to themselves.
The Boolean operators can be thought of as a function that implements an IF statement. If true, then return X, If false,  then return Y.
The constant true is a function that always returns X. The constant false is a function that always returns Y.


Interpreted conceptually, this would seem to say that "truth" is a binary function which returns its first argument, whereas "false" is a binary function which returns its second argument.

This is mistaking the map for the territory.

Interpreted conceptually, the word "truth" in the English language seems to imply that truth is a five-letter word written using the Latin alphabet.
Interpreted conceptually, digital circuits seem to imply that truth is a voltage and falsity is a lower voltage.
Interpreted conceptually, the map seems to imply that the territory is a printed sheet of paper.

These are all the same mistake. It is our choice to represent or encode truth as the function λx.λy.x in lambda calculus, just as it is our choice to encode truth as a word in English, or a voltage in a digital circuit. Generally, we do not choose encodings based on their resemblance to the concepts they encode. Rather, we choose encodings which are useful for the task at hand. @benrg's answer explains why this encoding is useful in lambda calculus.
Sometimes the encoding does bear a resemblance to what it encodes (e.g. the map shares some visual similarity with the territory, having roughly the same shapes as certain geographical features but at a much reduced scale). That resemblance tends to occur when it is useful relative to the purpose of the encoding. But we also often choose representations which have nothing in common with the things they represent.
For example, in this website's software I am represented by the number 53049, purely because sequential positive integers are useful for identifying rows in databases, and that happened to be the next unused postive integer when I joined the site. That number represents me in this one domain, but nobody would think to draw any conclusions about who I am from it.

As a little complement to @benrg's excellent answer, I think that this is a small misunderstanding:

So we can begin to motivate this choice of definition by noting that if true and false are to be values somewhere in this language, they will have to be lambda expressions. It would occur to me to include them as variables, then: true ∈ Variables, false ∈ Variables, and consider what relationships they need to have.

Usually in λ-calculus, the terms that are thought of as “values” are not variables but normal forms. The meaning of the Church-Rosser theorem can then be formulated as, ”a terminating program returns a unique value”.
Variables, instead, should be thought of as... variables, i.e. inputs from the environment.
